# Identity function with optional parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How could we change this identity function to make its parameter optional, such that it returns undefined when called with no arguments?

```js
function f<T>(x: T): T {
    return x;
}

var a: number = f(1);
var b: null = f(null);
var c: undefined = f(undefined);
```

The obvious approach doesn’t pass strictNullChecks:

```js
function f<T>(x?: T): T {
    return x; // TS2322
}
```

Adding a type assertion appears to solve the problem…

```js
function f<T>(x?: T): T {
    return x as T;
}

var d: undefined = f();
```

…but actually opens the door for incorrect code to fail at runtime:

```js
var e: number = f();
console.log(e.toExponential());
```

Giving the type parameter a default value doesn’t help:

```js
function f<T = undefined>(x?: T): T {
    return x as T;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be difficult to get the compiler to verify that your implementation is safe, so the best I think you'll do here is something that will guarantee that the caller cannot call it incorrectly, but where you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the "moral equivalent" to suppress warnings in the implementation.

The easiest way to do this is to implement `f` as an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
// call signatures
function f(): undefined;
function f<T>(x: T): T;
// impl signature
function f(x?: any) {
    return x;
}
```

Here you are supporting two call signatures: either a zero-argument call where the result is `undefined` and there is no generic type parameter, or a one-argument generic call where the result is the same as the input.  This should behave exactly as you expect:

```
var a = f(1); // number
var b = f(null); // null 
var c = f(undefined); // undefined
var d = f(); // undefined
var e: number = f(); // error! undefined is not number
```

An overloaded function is what I'm calling "morally equivalent" to a type assertion, because the implementation signature is allowed to be looser than any of the call signatures.  So you have to be careful to implement the function properly.

If for some reason you don't want overloads you can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) along with [rest tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to make a generic function which accepts zero or one arguments and whose return type is specifically dependent on the length of the argument list:

```
function f<P extends readonly [any?]>(
  ...x: P
): P extends readonly [infer R] ? R : undefined {
  return x as any;
}
```

That behaves the same way for the examples `a` through `e` above.  But you're still doing a type assertion (`as any` in the implementation) and it's more complicated and ugly.  The only  difference I see would be if you call it with a union-typed argument spread, like this:

```
var hmm = f(...Math.random() < 0.5 ? ["hey"] : []) // different
```

which works for the conditional `f` but not for the overloaded one.  I doubt you need it though.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AagUQEoBkUEEARJAbwCgykkAzAV2HgBcBLAe2BoAoBKALiXoATCNWbAIggNyUa9Jmw7UAPABUAfJwAe-FXyQrpVOgxbsumgPz8QwAJ7dSMqgCcIjWs46bDSAL4UqADcQZyQQJABeLgBGbkkkAHoEpGBaMAAjCGcZYND0yK5UgBsiuMTk4qKkHJCkeALqTiERMQkypIFgYVFxQRrQwQaeeI7mnol+pAh+VIysofbkrOdWZwBCTu7WweYoFNZGFLTM7MmACzAwIYA6W4BZEEYz6+cbQVYwHiQlJAAGa4ArEgLEgANoAIjOEFs4IAukh+KDYYsps4VusZGR-GRQJBYAhkABhFAAOUIAEkVOTSfgcI4jHJTIolAAFKaaRgQLp7Vwgd7AIq2ME2WwWWEaJxIW7XbRIFkyPRsiAcrmCHkQPnsQVgsTUeZYeEgrAIzYtXr0qhIVzuTxITRhPYinz+IK1cJRRqxEYVY5ZSb5D2cSooyrVV2heqBsbbFHR3qTQaB2NdM0TcNTGa+0JJ72o9EbOMSJC7faHWYnAJIXJIC5XQPSh5PF5vD5fH7-IEgiFQmHwk1IhwdVgAaxAthkHUh0PBSAAPqbxn0sUA)

Comment: sure did, that was really thorough!